# "Sorry to have kept you waiting" vs. "sorry for having kept you waiting"

Tags: grammaticality

Can I transform "I am sorry to have kept you waiting so long" into "I am sorry for having kept you waiting so long"? Is there a difference between them?

Additionally, is "I'm sorry having kept you waiting so long" grammatical?

Comment: They are all borderline ungrammatical in my dialect, where it would be "*for* so long". Other than that, same difference.

Comment: We do get an awful lot of these 'infinitive (to keep) versus present participle (keeping)' questions. Usually it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Definitely no need for _for_ for me. In most cases where either can be used (like here), _so long_ with no preposition tends to sound quite a bit better to my ear.

Comment: You can usually switch between "to" and "ing" like this with no difference in meaning.  I like to watch.  I like watching.  To be or not to be.  Being or not being.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry to have kept you waiting so long. It is fine but can be a bit better:

> I am sorry to have kept you waiting *for* so long.

I am sorry for having kept you waiting so long. It is fine but can be a bit better:

> I am sorry for having kept you waiting *for* so long.

I'm sorry having kept you waiting so long. Not so good. Better:

> I'm sorry *for* having kept you waiting *for* so long.

Comment: I wonder if this is a dialectal or purely idiolectal preference. To me, adding _for_ actually makes it sound less mellifluous. The most natural phrasing to me would be, “Sorry to keep you waiting so long”. (Obviously I agree completely with “I’m sorry having kept you waiting” is only borderline grammatical.)

Comment: I am sorry that you kept me waiting till the end, but you didn't explain the difference at all.

Comment: @Nawaz - "...you didn't explain the difference at all" is fine. "I am sorry that you kept me waiting till the end" is awkward.

Comment: @anongoodnurse: Yes. It is. It was an attempt to rhyme only; the thing after the _but_ is the real concern.